# Windows 11 ucrtbase.dll explorer crash 0xc0000409

Tags: windows-explorer, crash, windows-11

I have been having crashes with `explorer.exe` Does anyone know how I can fix this

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.22000.527, time stamp: 0x59dc9944
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.22000.1, time stamp: 0x00e78ce9
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000007dd7e
Faulting process id: 0x424
Faulting application start time: 0x01d844ce5adf2e65
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: 1950c5a3-3122-460a-a339-c0c2f9d3727c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I have clean installed both iGPU and GPU drivers and also, I cleared `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

**Update:**
I noticed that this mainly happens when I have edge open or when I open a game also maybe a mix of both and it crashes when I close some games

also here is some info about the crashes
https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/e4dc16afa8cf5a01ae686e82189a62e9#file-explorer-exe-14740-txt

Comment: Please look in Reliability Monitor to see all the errors that have been reported.

Comment: @John the only thing I see is https://gist.github.com/poqdavid/67f2e14662259c78a5ea9a4b4890370a

Comment: I have not seen this error before. Another thing to try is a new, test Windows User Account.  See if the error occurs in the new User Account.

Comment: @John I don't think it's my profile since it just crashes randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching and checking everything I couldn't find anything wrong with my PC so it felt like a bug and after installing [KB5011563](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/march-28-2022-kb5011563-os-build-22000-593-preview-40df54c9-b5a9-42e5-ae1c-9a33ff91ca91) all is good now

Answer (score 0):

Have today exactly same issue. But it cause blinking screen of windows (even on external display). Uninstalled GPU drivers, disabled discrete GPU used only internal nothing helped. Cleaned recent destinations as mentioned. But nothgin helped.
My issue is that absolutely prevent any work on Windows, as even start menu not acessible nor able to click to icons or desktop or windos key. So only way is call CTRL DEL ATL to task manager and then i can call CMD. But again even i write, it still grabing my cursor.
But in event log i´ve found almost same error code as here mentioned. Every 10seconds.

Its fresh install of W10, i´ve spent about 4 hours today, gone through all internet, but seems this need reinstall. Bad is that i am little afraid to get this issue again....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar issue: Explorer was crashing without stop, looping and driving me crazy. Event log said that "ucrtbase.dll" was crashing.

After hours of trying to solve I found the problem: I created a ramdrive and set the Temp folder to that ramdrive, as I have lots of memory and wanted things to run faster.

The Ramdrive failed to load, hence temp files were not able to be create, making explorer crash without a good explanation in the logs...

The fact that it did not say anything about failing to create temp files caused me to search and search and not have a working computer for 1.5 days.